# My gear icon thing up in the top right corner has turned red.. why?

Tags: unity, icons, panel

The gear icon on the top right has turned red. why?

[image: screenshot of my desktop]

Answer (score 5):

This happens when there's an update/upgrade that will only be completed after you restart.

This generaly only applies to kernel updates or, of course, upgrading to an ubuntu major release.

Comment: @Coy - if this answered your question, could you please mark it as answered :-)

Answer (score 4):

An update having been installed that requires a restart is *one* reason the icon will turn red. However, updates are generally installed via the `Update Manager` application, and it will also not give you an obvious way to quit, displaying a dialog with only a single `Restart` button in it, in the event of installing an update that requires a restart.

However, the gear icon will also turn red, when there is a problem with an account you have configured in `Online Accounts`, such as Twitter. When this occurs, an `Online accounts…` item will also appear in the menu, when you open it.